# Unhandled exceptions when using TPL while OnlyOnFaulted is presented

Tags: c#, exception, task-parallel-library, unobserved-exception

This is a sample code from a "C# 5.0 in a Nutshell"

```
TaskCreationOptions atp = TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent;
Task.Factory.StartNew (() =>
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew (() => { throw null; }, atp);
    Task.Factory.StartNew (() => { throw null; }, atp);
    Task.Factory.StartNew (() => { throw null; }, atp);
})
.ContinueWith (p => Console.WriteLine (p.Exception),
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

I have a "CLR exceptions": "break on user-unhandled" option checked in my VS2012 settings and running this code provides a VS's "NRE exception was unhandled by user code" popup on the `throw null;`

I've tried to try-catch exception on Wait in the ContinueWith and later but still got the unhandled exception.

I feel like a solution with turning "CLR exceptions": "break on user-unhandled" off seems wrong, because I actually handle this exception. So what is the right way to manage it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *reason* for the debugger stopping execution is that "Break on user-unhandled exceptions" will [break on any exception that is not handled by a handler in user code ("My Code").](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/038tzxdw.aspx)

Since the TPL, which is the one catching the exception, is [not considered user code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc(v=vs.100).aspx), the debugger will consider the exception unhandled by user code.

The problem is, the TPL does not have any other way to trigger [TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions.aspx), so I'm afraid you're probably stuck seeing the exceptions.

Hopefully, getting exceptions isn't part of your normal flow. If it's not, seeing the exceptions as unhandled in the debugger may actually be a good thing for debugging errors in your task flow.