# Correct Way to Throw and Catch Exceptions using async/await

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, .net-4.5, async-await

All, please take the following code:

```
Task<bool> generateStageAsyncTask = null;
generateStageAsyncTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() =>
{
    return GenerateStage(ref workbook);
}, this.token,
   TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
   TaskScheduler.Default);

// Run core asynchroniously.
bool bGenerationSuccess = false;
try
{
    bGenerationSuccess = await generateStageAsyncTask;
}
catch (OperationCancelledException e)
{
    // Script cancellation.
    result.RunSucceeded = true;
    result.ResultInfo = "Script processing cancelled at the users request.";
    return result;
}
```

From within method `GenerateStage` I test and re-throw a `OperationCancelledException` as follows

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    if (e.GetType() == typeof(OperationCanceledException))
        throw e;
    else // <- Here it is saying that the thrown exception is unhandled.
    {
        // Do other stuff...
    }
}
```

But at the specified line above, it is stating that the re-thrown exception is unhandled. **I am wrapping my `await` in the first code snippet above with the appropriate `try/catch`, why is this `try/catch` not traping the re-thrown exception?**

Comment: Why are you not using `catch(OperationCanceledException)`?

Comment: What is `result`, where is it defined and where is it assigned?

Comment: Are you doing something to cancel the operation via the `CancelationTokenSource` that `token` came from?

Comment: result is used to display some information to the user right at the end of processing. I did have `catch(OperationCancelledException)` but switched it to the above for some testing. Yes, I am using the `CanellationTokenSource` to cancel the operation. Thanks for your time...

Comment: For the close vote, how is this 'Not a real question?'. What is being asked here is plain. The Try/Catch i am using around the await is not catching the rethrown exception - WHY??

Comment: I have also tested catching a generic `Exception` but this also causes the unhandled message to appear...

Comment: You should never rethrow exceptions like that, use just `throw;` instead (it doesn't reset the stack trace).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unhandled exceptions when using TPL while OnlyOnFaulted is presented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670522/unhandled-exceptions-when-using-tpl-while-onlyonfaulted-is-presented)

Comment: @svick thanks for the suggestion of not using `throw e;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [support request for the same problem from Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522955/exceptions-thrown-in-tasks-are-incorrectly-considered-unhandled). Disabling 'Just My Code' in

<kbd>Tools</kbd>-><kbd>Options</kbd>-><kbd>Debugging</kbd>-><kbd>General</kbd>

solves the problem.

Comment: And introduces another one, see this article: [VS2010 On the Impacts of Debugging with “Just My Code”](http://www.jaylee.org/post/2010/07/05/VS2010-On-the-Impacts-of-Debugging-with-Just-My-Code.aspx), after **Step Into “Debugging Experience” with JMC**. Basically, `Step In` stops working as expected in some cases.