# Exception not caught in Async / Await block

Tags: c#, exception, asynchronous, task

I'm just learning to use async / await in a windows Forms application, trying to keep my windows application responsive while doing slow actions. I see a difference in the handling of thrown exceptions.

If I use WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync, exceptions are caught by my code:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    this.textBox1.Text = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync("invalid address");
  }
  catch (Exception exc)
  {
    textBox1.Text = exc.Message;
  }
}
```

However, if I call an async function in my own code the exception is not caught:

```
private string GetText()
{
  throw new Exception("Tough luck!");
}

private async void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (var webClient = new WebClient())
  {
    try
    {
      this.textBox1.Text = await Task.Run(() => GetText());
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
      textBox1.Text = exc.Message;
    }
  }
}
```

As an answer to the stackoverflow question [Correct Way to Throw and Catch Exceptions using async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838733/correct-way-to-throw-and-catch-exceptions-using-async-await) someone advised to "disable 'Just My Code' in
Tools->Options->Debugging->General"

> After comments from Daniel Hilgarth (thanks Daniel!), I saw a copy - paste error. I've corrected it here. The problem still remains, but if you follow the advise to disable "just my code", the exception is properly caught.

So I guess the question is solved.

Comment: No repro. Just run without the debugger or continue after it breaks. Your exception is caught just fine.

Comment: But do read up on Task.Run() and await, it's not the ideal combo.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this:
You are throwing `Exception` but catching `WebException`.

Two solutions:

1. Throw a `WebException`
2. Catch a `Exception`

Solution 1 is preferred because you actually should never throw the unspecific `Exception`.

Comment: You're right, Copy - Paste problem, still it doesn't work, even after correction. However disabling "just my code" solves the problem I'll correct the question

Answer (score 1):

You're throwing a type `Exception` but only catching the more specific `WebException`. Catching `WebException` will only catch exceptions of type `WebException` or a type derived from it.

Comment: You're right, Copy - Paste problem, still it doesn't work, even after correction. However disabling "just my code" solves the problem I'll correct the question